# How do i select multiple options based on values that was split in jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, split

What is wrong/missing in my code.
I'm trying to makemultiple selections in options using multiple data concatenated from a string.

```
var nidText = "a;b;c;d"

var nidData = nidText.split(';');

$('#selectId option[value=' + nidData + ']').attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the `nidData` is an array! Not a string. So you need to use `$.each` or some looping function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var nidText = "a;b;c;d";
    var nidData = nidText.split(';');
    for (var nidDat in nidData)
        $('#selectId option[value="' + nidData[nidDat] + '"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fbCeL/

Comment: Not to confuse this issue, but you could have used jQuery `prop()` as well: `.prop('selected', true)` - available is jQuery 1.6+.

Comment: @ARGO First answer of mine was wrong. Please see the updated answer and fiddle. `:)`